# nextjs: shared components between pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've created a very simple [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/)-project with two pages.

Both pages include a basic layout component:

```
// Page Component  

render() {
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      This is page A
    </PageLayout>
  );
}
```

And PageLayout looks something like this:

```
// PageLayout

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So both pages use `PageLayout` to render a basic template that also includes the same `Header` on both pages.

My *problem* is that the `Header` component is re-created when navigating between the two pages. I think this is bad not only from a performance point of view, but also because in this case all DOM-Nodes and all React components loose their local state.

So I would like to know if there is something I am missing or how we can create shared components between pages that are reused properly (at least if their state did not change, of course).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't (by my experience with nextjs). If you don't want to lose the state in Header then you need to store it e.g. in redux.

Answer (score 3):

You have Two pages with common component:

Page **A**:

```
<A>
  <Common />
</A>
```

Page **B:**

```
<B>
  <Common />
</B>
```

[From the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types):

> Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down
>   the old tree and build the new tree from scratch. Going from `<a>` to
>   `<img>`, or from `<Article>` to `<Comment>`, or from `<Button>` to `<div>` - any
>   of those will lead to a full rebuild.

This is why you lose the state in Common (Header) component. Like I suggested in the comment you would have to use an external state like redux.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However my problem is not only related to local state, but also to the DOM itself. For example I have a CSS hover transition for my navigation (within the Header) that is always resetted when navigating between the pages. Now I'm just wondering if I can come around this issue when I create my own setup.

Comment: Because nextjs is server side rendered, you will get a full page load every time, so you can't do this. With a normal app (ie a create-react-app) with client side routing, you could have the router work inside the layout so that the same header is there all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a component with the name of layout

```
// components/layout.js

import Navbar from './navbar'
import Footer from './footer'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

And then rap your _app.js component like this

```
// pages/_app.js

import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

for more read https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts